What is the current status for the site name change proposal?
I see that there was once a tide of site name change proposal around April - May '12 (5 years ago). It seems that nothing has changed since then. What is the current status of this proposal? Is it officially declined, or just falls into abysmal? What is the opinion from the veterans, the Stack Exchange staffs and other stakeholders? What are some notable conclusions after this?
One link to start off: Whither a more inclusive site name?

You can find an exhaustive answer to this in the community review done in June 2016, which is summarized as:

We have noticed our site name might lead to confusion on what this
  site is, what new name should we use?

The name "Cognitive Sciences" can be interpreted to only welcome cognitive science and cognitive
  psychology, thus
  excluding, e.g., non-cognitive sub-disciplines of psychology. We have
  collected evidence
  showcasing that psychology and neuroscience is often perceived to be
  excluded.
There is a strong majority favoring a name change.
When choosing a new name, the url prefix needs to be considered as well.
Many popular suggestions follow the format "A and B": Cognitive Science and
  Psychology,
  Psychology and
  Neuroscience, Mind
  and Brain.
An attempt at getting an overview of consensus resulted in two favorites (Psychology and Neuroscience, and Mind and
  Brain), with
  Psychology and
  Neuroscience as a
  clear winner.
Unfortunately these suggestions go against the naming standards of SE, which 'suggest'
  avoiding "X and B" like names.
Regardless, this is a topic which keeps resurfacing. The name keeps causing confusion even for active researchers in the
  fields.



I noticed you found the community review post. At the top of this post a link is included to our planned efforts on a Cognitive Sciences reboot, as part of which a site name change is on the agenda.

I admire the effort you've spent on this site

If you want to contribute, at the moment we would really value any further input on the two main issues to be discussed: Refining our target audience, Refining scope and new site name Any input is welcomed!

I suppose that you or someone else should make a meta post announcing which problems needs to be focused, then stick it on the side bar
